# Get host domain from URL?

Tags: c#, string, url, httpwebrequest, uri

how to get host domain from a string URL?

GetDomain has 1 input "URL", 1 Output "Domain"

Example1

```
INPUT: http://support.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
OUTPUT: support.domain.com
```

Example2

```
INPUT: http://www.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
OUTPUT: www.domain.com
```

Example3

```
INPUT: http://localhost/default.aspx?id=12345
OUTPUT: localhost
```

Comment: It seems the question is for the _host_ in the URL, and not the **domain** of the host, unless I completely misunderstand "host domain" (as opposed to just "host"). The fact that the answer is along the lines of **Uri.Host** kind of support that the question should be updated to better reflect and align with the desired examples in the question and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

You can use `Request` object or `Uri` object to get host of url.

Using [**Request.Url**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

```
string host = Request.Url.Host;
```

Using [**Uri**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx)

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/");   
string host = myUri.Host;  // host is "www.contoso.com"
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use Request.Url,  but Visual Studio still returns Cannot resolve symbol 'Request'. I do not know what is wrong. I use Visual Studio 2010 and Net Framework 4.0. Can anybody explain the symptom? Thanks

Comment: You need to have Request object available which you have in web pages / services but not behind that by default. You can Uri class if you do not have Request object available

Answer (score 95):

Try like this;

```
Uri.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority )
```

> Defines the parts of a URI for the Uri.GetLeftPart method.

---

> http://www.contoso.com/index.htm?date=today --> http://www.contoso.com
>
> http://www.contoso.com/index.htm#main --> http://www.contoso.com
>
> nntp://news.contoso.com/123456@contoso.com --> nntp://news.contoso.com
>
> file://server/filename.ext --> file://server

```
Uri uriAddress = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/index.htm#search");
Console.WriteLine("The path of this Uri is {0}", uriAddress.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
```

[`Demo`](http://ideone.com/SOgBUK)

Answer (score 30):

Use [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class and use [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property

```
Uri url = new Uri(@"http://support.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345");
Console.WriteLine(url.Host);
```

Answer (score 21):

try following statement

```
 Uri myuri = new Uri(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
 string pathQuery = myuri.PathAndQuery;
 string hostName = myuri.ToString().Replace(pathQuery , "");
```

Example1

```
 Input : http://localhost:4366/Default.aspx?id=notlogin
 Ouput : http://localhost:4366
```

Example2

```
 Input : http://support.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
 Output: support.domain.com
```

Comment: doesn't work if  myuri.PathAndQuery  is "/"  it just replace "/" with ""

Answer (score 13):

The best way, and the right way to do it is using `Uri.Authority` field

Load and use Uri like so :

```
Uri NewUri;

if (Uri.TryCreate([string with your Url], UriKind.Absolute, out NewUri))
{
     Console.Writeline(NewUri.Authority);
}

Input : http://support.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
Output : support.domain.com

Input : http://www.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345
output : www.domain.com

Input : http://localhost/default.aspx?id=12345
Output : localhost
```

If you want to manipulate Url, using Uri object is the good way to do it. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
 var url = Regex.Match(url, @"(http:|https:)\/\/(.*?)\/");
```

INPUT = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/";

OUTPUT = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine(GetDomain.GetDomainFromUrl("http://support.domain.com/default.aspx?id=12345"));
```

It will output support.domain.com

Or try

```
Uri.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Authority )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should construct your string as [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx) object and [Authority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx) property returns what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string DownloadImage(string URL, string MetaIcon,string folder,string name)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient oClient = new WebClient();

            string LocalState = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;

            string storesIcons = Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalState + folder).ToString();

            string path = Path.Combine(storesIcons, name + ".png");

            
            //si la imagen no es valida ej "/icon.png"
            if (!TextBoxEvent.IsValidURL(MetaIcon))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
                string DownloadImage = "https://" + uri.Host + MetaIcon;

                oClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(DownloadImage), path);
            }
            //si la imagen tiene todo ej https://www.mercadolibre.com/icon.png
            else
            {
                oClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(MetaIcon), path);
            }

            return path;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will work for all kinds of URLs.

```
public string GetDomainFromUrl(string url)
{
    url = url.Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", ""); //Remove the prefix
    string[] fragments = url.Split('/');
    return fragments[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will take only domain name ([www.bla.com](http://www.bla.com) -> bla)

no Uri required

```
static string GetDomainNameOnly(string s)
    {
        string domainOnly = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (s.Contains("."))
            {
                string domain = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('.', s.LastIndexOf('.') - 1) + 1);
                string countryDomain = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('.'));
                domainOnly = domain.Replace(countryDomain, "");
            }
            else
                domainOnly = s;
        }
        return domainOnly;
    }
```

Comment: That's not what is asked. The domain should contains www. and .com

Answer (score -4):

WWW is an alias, so you don't need it if you want a domain.
Here is my litllte function to get the real domain from a string

```
private string GetDomain(string url)
    {
        string[] split = url.Split('.');
        if (split.Length > 2)
            return split[split.Length - 2] + "." + split[split.Length - 1];
        else
            return url;

    }
```