# Get List of Domains Hosted on Remote IP

Tags: c#, web-hosting

A far out requirement finds me in a situation where I need to know how many Domains or Web Site URL's hosted in a remote Server.

This is close: [Get host domain from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211973/get-host-domain-from-url)

But the other way around.

I have the IP, but I want to know what else is hosted on this IP.

This is not for hacking purposes, its a tool to check my site's availability and see if my Web Hosting Company is doing the right thing by me. I have had issues with my site sometimes being very slow and I believe its a bandwidth problem, possibly because too many sites are hosted on the server.

Thanks.

[**EDIT**]

I guess you could say, I want to Query Remote Web Hosting Service, E,G: IIS, or Apache as to how many Websites are setup.

Not really a DNS query as such.

Comment: Does `Dns.GetHostEntry()` work for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx. It returns `IPHostEntry` which has an `Aliases` property, which may have what you want? Sorry, I dont know of a ip with multiple hosts, so I couldn't test.

Comment: Are you looking for [Reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)?

Comment: Do you have Direct Access to ISS?  This is a security issue, if you don't have direct access then NO you'll never get this information ever.

Comment: No, I don't have direct access. Yes thought this would be a hard job. I thought some sort of DNS Query may pull it off but alas no, nothing I have tried works.