# How to retrieve host from string

Tags: c#, string, http, tcp, request

I have a request as a **string (due to working on tcp level)** and I would like to only get the host:

```
GET http://www.mrjacks.nl/ HTTP/1.1
cache - control: no - cache
Postman - Token: 037a5930 - 715d - 477d - a1d2 - d9445e6f675c
User - Agent: PostmanRuntime / 7.2.0
Accept: */*
Host: www.mrjacks.nl
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

In this case I want to get "www.mrjacks.nl".

The programming languague I'm using is C#.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this url? Through Regex or some other Class? I'm new to regex and I've tried messing around with it a little bit, but without success

Comment: `I've tried messing around with it a little bit` please share what you tried. We don't want to post solutions you already tried.

Comment: @Reniuz unfortunately I don't have the regex anymore :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not so hard to do some string manipulations. First thing to do is to search the line with "Host:" word and when you find it - remove the "Host: " word from that line. The leftover will be the address.

```
string s = @"GET http://www.mrjacks.nl/ HTTP/1.1
             cache - control: no - cache
             Postman - Token: 037a5930 - 715d - 477d - a1d2 - d9445e6f675c
             User - Agent: PostmanRuntime / 7.2.0
             Accept: */*
             Host: www.mrjacks.nl
             accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
             Connection: keep-alive";
var lines = s.Split('\n');
string result = "no result";
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if(line.StartsWith("Host:"))
    {
        result = line.Replace("Host: ", "");
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: @juser in ALL your questions don't forget to accept answers if they where useful .

Answer (score 0):

Please see :-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212007/385965

Depending on how you're building the HTTP request the URL might already be stored in a Uri class based property.

Comment: I'm in a rep no mans land where I can comment here but not on the original post apparently.