# How to get host name in startup file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

My API is running on IIS with "www.api-example.com". How can I get "api-example" in startup file ConfigureServices method?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //string hostName = ...

        //*** App Settings Services
        services.AddAppServices(Configuration);

        //*** Business Services
        services.AddBusinessServicesCollection();
         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My API is running on IIS with "www.api-example.com". How can I get
> "api-example" in startup file ConfigureServices method?

No we cannot, because `ConfigureServices` invocked before constructing `Startup` so if we try to inject, it will through exception, even if we declare at global variable in that scenario it will always be null. Application startup happens only once, and long before any request has been received.

**Proper Way to Get Main Host/Domain Name:**

```
          app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
               var hostUrl = context.Request.Host.Host;
                Console.WriteLine(hostUrl);
                return next.Invoke();
            });
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I want to run this middleware just first request. Because I need this in just first request. Is it possible?

Comment: How would trace if the request is first or not? Need to do additional hassle.

Comment: Do you think this method will affect the performance of the program?

Comment: It won't because  it will just act as an other middleware does. For instance, Authentication middleware, CORS middleware and so on. So there shouldn't be any critical performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.Use((context,next) =>
 {
    var url = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
    return next.Invoke();
 });
```

host name [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211973/get-host-domain-from-url)

Comment: I can use this in Configure method. Is there any way to get this url in ConfigureServices?